# How to implement expand/collapse rows in HTML table

Tags: r, dt, kableextra, reactable

I would like to make some rows expand on click, i.e. by clicking on the arrow. Is there a way in `reactable` to add java script code to specific rows? There exists and option for expanding/collapsing all rows on click in `reactable` (see [here](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#row-expansion-toggle-button)), but it does not do exactly what I need. Is there any reactable/javascript guru out there who has an idea how this might be feasible.

The required output is designed with `kableExtra` but I think my problem is more suited for `reactable`.

```
df_open <- tibble::tibble(
  Category = c("Fruits &#x25bc;&#xFE0E;", "Apple", "Banana",
               "Kiwi", "Vegetable &#x25bc;&#xFE0E;", "Carrots &#x25bc;&#xFE0E;", "Red Carrots", "Orange Carrots", "Diary"), 
  Value_sum = c(1:9), 
  Value_one = c(10:18),
  Value_two = c(200:208)
)

df_closed <- tibble::tibble(
  Category = c("Fruits &#x25b6;&#xFE0E","Vegetable &#x25b6;&#xFE0E;",  "Diary"), 
  Value_sum = c(1, 5,9), 
  Value_one = c(10,14,18),
  Value_two = c(200, 204,208)
)


library(kableExtra)

# all collapsed, everything shown
kbl(df_open, escape = FALSE) |> 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "bordered") |> 
  row_spec(row = c(2:4, 6), extra_css = "padding-left:30px;") |> 
  row_spec(row = c(7,8), extra_css = "padding-left:50px")
```

**Completely unfolded table:**
[image]

```
# all closed
kbl(df_closed, escape = FALSE) |> 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "bordered")
```

**Completely folded table:**

[image]

**Raw Data**:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
  Category = c("Fruits", "Apple", "Banana", "Kiwi", "Vegetable", "Carrots", "Red Carrots", "Orange Carrots", "Diary"), 
  Value_sum = c(1:9), 
  Value_one = c(10:18),
  Value_two = c(200:208), 
  Another_column = "ABC"
)
```

---

**My attempt** using this [blog post](https://www.vishalkatti.com/posts/drilldown-with-reactable/)

```
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)
top_level <- df |> 
  mutate(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2, 2,2,3),
         id_large = c(1, NA, NA, NA,2, NA, NA, NA, 3)) |> 
  filter(!is.na(id_large)) |> 
  relocate(id, .before = 1) |> 
  select(-id_large)

second_level <- df |> 
  mutate(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2, 2,2,3),
         id_large = c(1, NA, NA, NA,2, NA, NA, NA, 3)) |> 
  filter(is.na(id_large)) |> 
  relocate(id, .before = 1) |> 
  select(-id_large)


reactable(
  data       = top_level,
  compact    = TRUE, 
  striped    = TRUE, 
  resizable  = TRUE, 
  columns    = list(
  id   = colDef(name = "ID", show = FALSE)),
  details = function(index) { # index is the row number of current row.
    sec_lvl = second_level[second_level$id == top_level$id[index], ] 
    reactable(data       = sec_lvl,
              compact    = TRUE, 
              bordered   = TRUE, 
              resizable  = TRUE,
              colna
              columns    = list(
                id   = colDef(name = "ID", show = FALSE))
    )
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is currently possible with {reactable} - but it looks like an open feature request: https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/147

The {DT} package might be able to do something like this. Using the code in this blog post: https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DT_childTables.html you can create something similar. In the example below, the `NestedData` function and `callback` are copied directly from the blog post.

The idea is to store your data as a nested list. Ideally, you'd have some column in your `df` data frame that identifies what level the table is and use that to subset it, rather than manually creating the different data frames as I've done here.

```r
main <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Category,          ~Value_sum, ~Value_one, ~Value_two, ~Another_column,
  "Fruits",                 1,        10,       200, "ABC", 
  "Vegetable",              5,        14,       204, "ABC",  
  "Dairy",                  9,        18,       208, "ABC",  
)

fruits <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Category,          ~Value_sum, ~Value_one, ~Value_two, ~Another_column,
  "Apple",                 2,        11,       200, "ABC", 
  "Banana",                3,        12,       201, "ABC",  
  "Kiwi",                  4,        13,       202, "ABC",  
) 

veg <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Category,          ~Value_sum, ~Value_one, ~Value_two, ~Another_column,
  "Carrots",                 6,        15,       205, "ABC"
)

carrots <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Category,          ~Value_sum, ~Value_one, ~Value_two, ~Another_column,
  "Red Carrots",                 2,        11,       200, "ABC", 
  "Oraneg Carrots",                3,        12,       201, "ABC"
  ) 

Dat <- NestedData(
  dat = main, 
  children = list(
    fruits, 
    list(  
      veg, 
      children = list(
        carrots
      )
    ), 
    data.frame(NULL)
  )
)

library(DT)
datatable(
  Dat, 
  callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  options = list(
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        visible = FALSE, 
        targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
      ),
      list(
        orderable = FALSE, 
        className = "details-control", 
        targets = colIdx
      ),
      list(
        className = "dt-center", 
        targets = "_all"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

gives something like this:

[image]